# Function object: Invalid argument

Tags: c++, stl

I am quite new to C++ and STL. There is something that I don't understand here:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void operator()(int& bar) { std::cout << bar << std::endl; }
};

int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);

    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), Foo); // Invalid argument Foo

    Foo foo;
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), foo); // Valid argument foo

    return 0;
}
```

Why does the first attempt give an Invalid Argument error?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `Foo` is a class (i.e. a *type*), whereas `foo` is an instance (i.e. an *object*).  `for_each()` takes an object to work with.

Bear in mind that in C++, types are not [*first-class*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen); they cannot be passed to functions, etc. (however, they can be used as function-template parameters).

Answer (score 2):

Because `std::for_each` needs an object instead of a class. `Foo` is just a type.

Your code is equivalant to this one:

```
int foo;
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), int); // the third parameter is incorrect, it must be "foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

`foo` is a variable of type `Foo`, but `Foo` is a type. It cannot be used as a C++ function argument, only as a template argument.

**Long answer:**

A C++ function takes values as argument, not types.

`std::for_each` is not a C++ function, it is a **function template**.

A template is a *mathematical function* taking C++ types (or sometimes constants) as arguments. A class template is a function from types (or constants) to classes. A function template is a function from types (or constants) to C++ function.

When applied to adequate C++ types (one iterator type, one functor type), `std::for_each` maps to a C++ function.

Here the template arguments of `std::for_each` are deduced from the argument list:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), foo);
```

because the types of `v.begin()`, `v.end()`, `foo` are resp. `std::vector<int>::iterator`, `std::vector<int>::iterator`, `Foo`, the compiler can infer the template arguments of `std::for_each`.

You can supply template argument explicitly even where they can be deduced:

`std::for_each<std::vector<int>::iterator, Foo> (v.begin(), v.end(), foo);`

You cannot use a type where a value is expected, or a value where a type is expected.